# Automatic frameworks linking doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, import

Today I learned that `@import` statement actually can help to link frameworks automatically.

Okay, I created a project, added a `WebView`. It was throwing me an error that `WebView` is undefined. Okay, I wrote `@import WebKit` — and the error was gone and all the `WebView` methods were available to me.

...I ran the application and it crashed with

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (WebView)'`

Then I've added the `WebKit.framework` manually and... it worked. So what's the point of this `@import` statement? The automatic linking is turned on...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`import` imports *headers*. Thus, the name WebView becomes defined, along with the methods and other stuff in WebKit, and your code can *compile*. Linking links *code* - the code in which WebView actually lives and breathes and has its being - and so your code can *run*.

Normally, if you import a framework using `@import`, both things happen. You can compile your code because of the import, and you can run the code in the framework because the import also performs automatic linking.

But you are instantiating a WebView *from a nib*. Therefore you also have to link explicitly or you'll crash when the nib loads. The same is true if you were to use a MapView *in a nib* — you'd need to link MapKit explicitly or you'd crash when the nib loads.